# I want to add a "spheres" to my data cluster

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, scikit-learn, k-means

I want to add a kind of "spheres" to my data cluster.

My data cluster is this, which does not have ""spheres".

[image]

And this is my code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use('ggplot')
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

MY_FILE='total_watt.csv'
date = []
consumption = []

df = pd.read_csv(MY_FILE, parse_dates=[0], index_col=[0])
df = df.resample('1D', how='sum')
df = df.dropna()

date = df.index.tolist()
date = [x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for x in date]
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

encoder = LabelEncoder()
date_numeric = encoder.fit_transform(date)
consumption = df[df.columns[0]].values

X = np.array([date_numeric, consumption]).T

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
kmeans.fit(X)

centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
labels = kmeans.labels_

print(centroids)
print(labels)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))
rect = fig.patch
rect.set_facecolor('#2D2B2B')



colors = ["b.","r.","g."]

for i in range(len(X)):
    print("coordinate:",encoder.inverse_transform(X[i,0].astype(int)), X[i,1], "label:", labels[i])
    ax.plot(X[i][0], X[i][1], colors[labels[i]], markersize = 10)
ax.scatter(centroids[:, 0],centroids[:, 1], marker = "x", s=150, linewidths = 5, zorder = 10)
a = np.arange(0, len(X), 5)
ax.set_xticks(a)
ax.set_xticklabels(encoder.inverse_transform(a.astype(int)))
ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='lightseagreen')
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='lightseagreen')
plt.scatter(centroids[:, 0],centroids[:, 1], marker = "x", s=100, c="black", linewidths = 5, zorder = 10)
ax.set_title('Energy consumptions Clusters (high/medium/low)', color='gold')
ax.set_xlabel('time', color='gold')
ax.set_ylabel('date(year 2011)', color='gold')


plt.show()
```

"Spheres" is area which surroundings plot(cluster), as this picture.

[image]

I tried to google it.

But when I type "matplotlib spheres", I could not get any result..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample graph in your post looks like resulting from `Generalized Gaussian Mixture` where each sphere is a Gaussian 2-d density.

I'll write up a sample code shortly to demonstrate how to use `GMM` on your dataset and do this kind of plotting.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use('ggplot')
import pandas as pd
# code changes here
# ===========================================
from sklearn.mixture import GMM
# ===========================================
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

# replace it with you file path
MY_FILE='/home/Jian/Downloads/total_watt.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(MY_FILE, parse_dates=[0], index_col=[0])
df = df.resample('1D', how='sum')
df = df.dropna()

date = df.index.tolist()
date = [x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for x in date]

encoder = LabelEncoder()
date_numeric = encoder.fit_transform(date)
consumption = df[df.columns[0]].values

X = np.array([date_numeric, consumption]).T


# code changes here
# ===========================================
gmm = GMM(n_components=3, random_state=0)
gmm.fit(X)
y_pred = gmm.predict(X)

# the center is given by mean
gmm.means_

# ===========================================

import matplotlib as mpl
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))

for i, color in enumerate('rgb'):
    # sphere background
    width, height = 2 * 1.96 * np.sqrt(np.diagonal(gmm._get_covars()[i]))
    ell = mpl.patches.Ellipse(gmm.means_[i], width, height, color=color)
    ell.set_alpha(0.1)
    ax.add_artist(ell)
    # data points
    X_data = X[y_pred == i]
    ax.scatter(X_data[:,0], X_data[:,1], color=color)
    # center
    ax.scatter(gmm.means_[i][0], gmm.means_[i][1], marker='x', s=100, c=color)


ax.set_title('Energy consumptions Clusters (high/medium/low)', color='gold')
ax.set_xlabel('time', color='gold')
ax.set_ylabel('date(year 2011)', color='gold')
a = np.arange(0, len(X), 5)
ax.set_xticks(a)
ax.set_xticklabels(encoder.inverse_transform(a.astype(int)))
ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='lightseagreen')
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='lightseagreen')
```

[image]

Comment: @SuzukiSoma Just updated my post. Please have a look. :-)

Comment: @SuzukiSoma You are most welcome. Glad that it helped. If you wish to spend some time on learning `sci-kit`, you can start with its online user guide http://scikit-learn.org/stable/user_guide.html Many useful concepts and example codes are available there.

Comment: By the way, why you set 2 * 1.96??

Comment: @SuzukiSoma both are fine. the goal is to set a two-sided confidence interval. 1.96 is 2 standard deviation of Gaussian distribution. Multiplying a further 2 makes it two-sided.

Comment: You could do that also with `Kmeans`, calculating the standard deviations in `x` and `y` directions between points in every cluster and their centre of mass, then plotting corresponding ellipses.